# Comic book blob monster covered in eyes engulfs helpless young woman!

Tags: story-identification

I wonder if anyone can help... I am trying to locate a comic book story - DC comics I think - from around the mid 1970s. It featured a couple (I'm sure their names were Fred and Mary) who encounter a sort of redneck/hillbilly family out in the backwoods and the man falls for the young woman of the family, whose name was Gloria. Mary falls victim to Gloria's brother (?) who is a shape shifting monster. In its hideous form (a sort of pink, gelatinous mound covered in eyes) it engulfs Mary who pleads for help from Fred, who abandons her to her fate. A pretty freaky, gruesome little tale which left an indelible imprint on my impressionable teenage mind...can anyone out there throw any light whatsoever on this? I'd be most grateful - but if not, thanks anyway for sparing the time to read this!

Comment: I'm about 95% sure this isn't it, but from the title I thought it might be, so I'll just post it in the hopes somebody googling might find this question and be looking for [The Famileech](https://www.technohol.com/new-universe/pitt/famileech.asp) from Marvel's New Universe, which started as a family exposed to mutagenic goo in the crater that was once Pittsburgh who merged together and began absorbing others as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### *All in the Family*

According to the description on [this](http://www.scaryforkids.com/all-in-the-family/) website:

> One night, a married couple named Fred and Mary are out for a drive
>   when their car swerves off the road and they find themselves stranded
>   in a swamp.

The “gelatinous mound” is indeed Gloria’s brother:

> They tell him they are Gloria’s parents and the hideous blob is
>   Gloria’s brother. When he asks where Gloria is, they tell him she is
>   “changing into something more comfortable…”

Here’s the pink mound with eyes:

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU!!! so very much - this is indeed the exact comic strip. I had remembered it reasonably accurately after all these years... never dreamt I'd actually see it again! I really am most grateful.